# Html & attachments dropped after using tidmessage.savetofile and loadfromfile

Tags: indy10

I use a Mac program to create reasonable elegant looking emails for our club members. I send the email to a google account, read it into a Delphi Windows program using POP3 and save it for later sending using tidmessage.savetofile. Later I use loadfromfile, clear the header and create new header info to send as bulk email to members. Using Indy 9, I never had to consider using the nodecode and/or noencode options. The defaults just worked. When a more secure SMTP connection was forced by our ISP, I took the opportunity to upgrade to Indy 10. I then found that the initial savetofile worked fine, but the subsequent loadfromfile dropped the html content and attachments. An email of 180k would be truncated to less than 4k for instance, if I immediately issued a savetofile after the loadfromfile.

I switched to using nodecode/noencode = true, but if I clear the header, I lose all of the email body, plain/html/attachments. If I leave the header and just update the bits I need, web mail such as yahoo shows a blank email, while programs like Outlook and OE show the email correctly.

Is there a debug option somewhere I can determine what Indy doesn't like about the email so I can allow Indy to parse the email correctly?

I saw that someone had a similar problem using IMAP, but as I'm not, I don't think the fix or circumvention is likely to help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, a bit more delving and it appears that the Mac program is adding a spurious boundary clause to the content-type statement preceding the html section, so it has 2 boundary clauses, one of them with no other references in the email. Removing that allows Indy to parse the email correctly. It doesn't happen every time, but I've reported it to Equinux.